# Entity Framework code first migration and the Set<T> method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

If I'm using entity framework migration, and I call the `.Set<T>()` method manually on my context, will this trigger a change in the context definition?

I was playing around with an IUunitOfWork interface applied to my context and I started to get migration exceptions.

What causes this? is it the fact that the context now have more methods that expose `IDbSet<T>` so that the migration thinks that it needs to create a new table or what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, methods shouldn't trigger scaffolding, but any DbSet *properties* will. You can extend your DbContext class to add your properties, and execute your migration against the base class; or alternatively, you can create a separate DbContext used just for migrations (also useful if you want to maintain multiple discrete contexts but you want to use migrations for all of them, as you can only enable migrations for one context in a project.)